# redux-form: Field value does not reflect state change

Tags: redux-form

I have started using redux-form just recently and found an issue which I am not sure how to solve and although I suppose it must be something really easy I am not able to find answer anywhere.

Issue: Value of the Field (redux-form Field) is not updated when state changes.

Example*:

```
 const SimpleForm = (props) => {
    return (
        <Form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>            
            <Field value={props.amount} onChange={props.amountChanged}
                name="amount" component={renderField} />

            <input value={props.amount} type="text" onChange={props.amountChanged} />
        </Form>
    );
};

const renderField = (field) => (
    <div className="input-row">
        <input {...field.input} type="text" />
        {field.meta.touched && field.meta.error && <span className="error">{field.meta.error}</span>}
    </div>
)

export default reduxForm({ form: 'SimpleForm' })(SimpleForm);
```

**Expected Result:**

- initial value in both inputs is same (and equals to props.amount)
- when I change value in one of the inputs the second input is updated with a new value

**Actual Result:**

- initial value in input 'wrapped' into redux-form field is not populated
- when I change value in 'redux-form input' -> 'normal input' is updated BUT 
      when I change value in 'normal input' -> 'redux form input' is not updated

**Question:**

- does anybody happen to know why redux-form input is not updated when state value is changed?

*Please note that: onChange just basically triggers action which is handled by reducers and state is updated with new amount; 'renderField' function is taken from [redux-form component usage page](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/api/Field.md/#usage) and SimpleForm is used in some really basic 'statefull' container